# Change time in azure log analytics

Tags: azure-log-analytics

In 'Azure log Analytics' logs are saved all day. Is there any way to change the time of saving? I mean changing time so that logs are saved for example between 6:00 AM to 9:00 PM?

It would be great if you send an screenshot.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean only save the logs between 6:00 AM to 9:00 PM?

Comment: Yes. I'm only interested to logs which are saved between these times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such option when log into Azure Log Analytics. You can only control the `log categories` when configuring logs into Azure Log Analytics via UI or rest api.

If you are only interested the data in a specified time range, you can try to write a query to fetch these logs in Azure Log Analytics.